Transplanting Daphnia
I transplanted a Daphnia from 10” being in the ground to a large pot.
Now it is wilting . It also had burned leaves that I cut off. Is it dying?


I felt bad after seeing this situation but before concluding, I want to know the frequency of water  and how much sunlight exposure it's getting
